# Regex positive lookahead when lookahead data doesn't exist (PCRE)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match out a string which will have a format similar to the following:

```
username=joe password='this! is a password with "quotes" and spaces#913 custom1 customd afd weirdhuh? custom1=myvalue
```

To explain in more detail, this is a list of variables separated by equal signs.  The valid variables that can be passed are: username, password, and customX (where X is any number of digit(s)).

I am specifically trying to match out the password field as the passed variable can technically have any number of quotes, spaces, etc that are valid characters.  I have decided that the best "break point" to use to determine when the password string terminates is the existence of a "customX=" string which infers that the next variable is starting.

Therefore, in the above example the actual password would be:

```
'this! is a password with "quotes" and spaces#913 custom1 customd afd weird huh?
```

I have arrived at the following regex:

```
(?i)password(?-i)=.+?(?= (?i)custom(?-i)\d+=)
```

This appears to match the following:

```
password='this! is a password with "quotes" and spaces#913 custom1 customd afd weird huh?
```

This is in effect what I want (I can easily parse out the "password="), but the problem is this regex only seems to work if there is an existence of that final "custom1=myvalue" at the end of the string.  If that is removed, then there is no match at all.

I need to be able to match the password string regardless if that final value is there or not.

Bonus points if you can strip out the "password=" to end up only with the actual password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the problem is this regex only seems to work if there is an existence of that final "custom1=myvalue"

You can add an optional end of string to match instead of `custom1=myvalue`:
`(?i)password(?-i)=.+?((?= (?i)custom(?-i)\d+=)|$)`

> Bonus points if you can strip out the "password=" to end up only with the actual password.

Use lookbehind when you match `password=`:
`(?<=(?i)password(?-i)=).+?((?= (?i)custom(?-i)\d+=)|$)`

Comment: Thanks Máté. I have been researching both options more since I posted and arrived at the exact solutions you have provided for both issues.  I was coming back here to post those and ask if overall this regex was relatively optimal for what I was looking to do.  The fact that you have suggested the same things I came up with is a good vote of confidence!

Comment: Actually, the solution I came up with was slightly different.  I used "(?<=(?i)password(?-i)=).+?(?= (?i)custom(?-i)\d+=|$)" .  In your answer you have used another set of parenthesis to group the lookahead.  Both seem to work, can you explain why you need that extra grouping?  thx.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure regex engine recognize options well, but you're right, that extra grouping isn't necessary